# Convert Date with milliseconds to another date format

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat

I have a date passed as a String which has date with millisecond format see below:

```
String dateMilli = "2014-08-21 09:11:44.187";
```

How can I convert this to date format with this format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
or 
2014-08-21T10:39:41
```

I have this so far but its not working

```
Date tempDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(dateMilli);
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");  
dateFormat.format(tempDate);
System.out.println(" date format: "+ dateFormat.toString());

Output:
date format: java.text.SimpleDateFormat@6b2ed43a
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [String Date Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998909/string-date-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing out the DateFormat object -- don't do that! You need to use that DateFormat object to parse a String to a Date or format the date to a String and then print the String returned. Please look at the API for [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) and [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to learn about the parse and format methods.

You would need two SimpleDateFormat objects:

- One to be used to convert Strings in the first format into a Date.

  - You would do by calling the format's `parse(String s)` method.
- And the other SimpleDateFormat would be used to format the Date into a String of the second type:

  - You do this by calling the format's `format(Date d)` method.
  - Then simply print out this String returned.
- You should never try to print the DateFormat object itself as that makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your printing the results of the `DateFormat` object, you need to apply the format to the `Date` and print that instead...

```
String formatted = dateFormat.format(tempDate);
System.out.println(" date format: "+ formatted);
```

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer, I'll try this